# Find the minimum value of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, maxima-minima

If the minimum value of $f\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin ^6\left(x\right)}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos ^6\left(x\right)}\right),\:x\:∈\:\left(0,\:\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ is $m$, find $\sqrt m$.

How do I differentiate this function without making the problem unnecessarily complicated? If there are any other methods to finding the minimum value I am open to those too.

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: Would you mind providing an article of Cauchy Schwartz that could be understood by a high school student? I don't have knowledge of Cauchy Schwartz.

Comment: Let $s=\sin^2(x)$, then $s\in(0;1)$ and $f(s)=\left(1+{1\over s^3}\right)\left(1+{1\over (1-s)^3}\right)$.

Comment: [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-schwarz-inequality/) gives a nice overview.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating?  Or are you concerned that it will be too complicated?  (Sometimes, these problems simply during the calculation in ways that aren’t obvious at the outset)

Comment: You could begin by showing $\left(1+a^2\right) \left(1+b^2\right) \ge (1+ab)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the straightforward approach of finding stationary points, and it was not complicated.

Let $s=\sin{x}$ and $c=\cos{x}$.

$f'(x)=(1+s^{-6})(6c^{-7}s)+(-6s^{-7}c)(1+c^{-6})$

$=6c^{-7}s^{-7}(s^8+s^2-c^8-c^2)$

$=6c^{-7}s^{-7}(s^8+s^2-(1-s^2)^4-(1-s^2))$

$=6c^{-7}s^{-7}(2s^6-3s^4+3s^2-1)$

$=6c^{-7}s^{-7}(2s^2-1)(s^4-s^2+1)=0$

$s^2=\frac{1}{2}\implies c^2=\frac{1}{2}\implies f(x)=81$

Assume one of these stationary points is a local maximum. The curve approaches $\infty$ near the vertical asymptotes, so there must be a minimum with $f(x)<81$, but such a minimum does not exist. So all the stationary points are minimums.$\text{ }\therefore \sqrt{m}=9$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got the derivative so gracefully? Mine is soo messy.

Comment: @Anonymousstriker38596 I've added more details.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin ^6(x)}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos ^6(x)}\right)$$

Using the logarithmic differentiation and using multiple angles leads to
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1536 \cot (2 x)}{(\cos (4 x)-17) (\cos (4 x)+7)}$$ It seems to be quite simple now.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos(x)$, $f(x)$ is symmetric around $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.  This implies that $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a critical point.

Writing $f(x)=(1+\sin(x)^{-6})(1+\cos(x)^{-6})$, we find that
$$
f'(x)=-6\sin(x)^{-7}\cos(x)(1+\cos(x)^{-6})+6\cos(x)^{-7}\sin(x)(1+\sin(x)^{-6}).
$$

While this looks a bit messy, let's try for a second derivative.
$$
f''(x)=42\sin(x)^{-8}\cos(x)^2(1+\cos(x)^{-6})
+6\sin(x)^{-6}(1+\cos(x)^{-6})
-36\sin(x)^{-6}\cos(x)^{-6}
+42\cos(x)^{-8}\sin(x)^2(1+\sin(x)^{-6})
+6\cos(x)^{-6}(1+\sin(x)^{-6})
-36\cos(x)^{-6}\sin(x)^{-6}
$$

Again, this looks a bit messy, but we notice that almost all of the terms are positive, which gives us some home that the second derivative might only have one sign.  In fact, we can rewrite the second derivative as
$$
f''(x)=42\sin(x)^{-8}\cos(x)^2
+6\sin(x)^{-8}\cos(x)^{-4}
+6\sin(x)^{-6}(1+\cos(x)^{-6})
+42\cos(x)^{-8}\sin(x)^2
+6\cos(x)^{-8}\sin(x)^{-4}
+6\cos(x)^{-6}(1+\sin(x)^{-6}
+36\cos(x)^{-4}\sin(x)^{-4}(\sin(x)^{-2}-\cos(x)^{-2})^2.
$$

The idea in this step is to absorb the single negative term into a square. The second derivative is always positive, so the first derivative is always increasing.  Hence, the first derivative can have at most one critical point, which we already know is at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

All that's left is to compute the value of $f$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and to consider the behavior near the endpoints of $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Simplify the monster as $f''(x)=\frac{3}{2} (25 \cos (4 x)+\cos (8 x)+30) \csc ^8(x) \sec ^8(x)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood the rest of your solution, except for the first line. Could you possibly provide source or explain how you got to know that the function is symmetric about $\frac{\pi }{4}$?

Comment: @Anonymousstriker38596 Observe that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-(\frac{\pi}{4}-x))=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)$.  Therefore, $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)$ (by substituting $-x$ for $x$).  Now, show that $f(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=f(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, is it possible to just say that the f(x) is min when $\sin ^6\left(x\right)=\cos ^6\left(x\right)$ just because it is a symmetric function? Is there logic or mathematical proof to support this?

Comment: I meant without finding f'(x) and f''(x) is it possible to know that you get the min value of f(x) when $\sin ^6\left(x\right)=\cos ^6\left(x\right)$?

Comment: @Anonymousstriker38596 The symmetry isn't enough.  The symmetry will tell you that the midpoint is a critical point, but it is possible for there to be other critical points - think of a "W" shape, it's symmetric about its center, but there are other critical points than the center.

Comment: @Anonymousstriker38596 However, as others suggested, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can sometimes be used instead of derivatives to get that the minimum is attained.

Answer (score 2):

Without calculus, let $\,a = \sin^2(x)\,$, $\,b = \cos^2(x)\,$, then $\,f(x) = \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a^3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{b^3}\right)\,$, where $\,a,b \ge 0\,$ and $\,a+b=1\,$. By the [generalized means inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases):

- $\sqrt{ab} \le \dfrac{a+b}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \quad\implies\quad \dfrac{1}{ab} \ge 4 \quad\implies\quad \dfrac{1}{a^3b^3} \ge 4^3 = 64\;$;
- $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\frac{1}{a^3}+ \frac{1}{b^3}}} \le \dfrac{a+b}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \quad\implies\quad \dfrac{1}{a^3}+ \dfrac{1}{b^3} \ge 16\;$.

Then the following inequality holds, with equality iff $a=b = \dfrac{1}{2}$, or $|\sin(x)| = |\cos(x)| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$:

$$
f(x) = \left(1+\frac{1}{a^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{b^3}\right) \;=\; 1 + \frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{a^3b^3} \;\ge\; 1 + 16 + 64 = 81
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't really need to evaluate a complicated derivative.

The cosine and sine are symmetric around $\frac\pi 4$, and they are both monotone (in opposite directions).

Each of the factors varies monotonously between $2$ and $\infty$, which they achieve on the boundaries of the interval.

Consequently at the boundaries $f$ goes to $\infty$.

It follows that the minimum must be at the symmetric middle at $\frac\pi 4$.

Fill in to find:
$$f\Big(\frac \pi 4\Big)=\left(1+\frac{1}{(\frac 1{\sqrt 2})^6}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{(\frac 1{\sqrt 2})^6}\right)=9\cdot9$$
So $m=81$ and $\sqrt m=9$.

Comment: +1 Simple and sweet!

Comment: "*Each of the factors varies monotonously*" $\;-\;$ Yes, but that alone doesn't guarantee that their product varies monotonically. "*It follows that the minimum must be at the symmetric middle*" $\;-\;$ It's not obvious how this follows, at least not without further proof. Consider for example $\,(1+\sin^6(x))(1+ \cos^6(x))\,$, instead. It is symmetric around $\pi/4$, each factor varies monotonically on $(0, \pi/2)$, but the minimum is not unique and is not attained in the middle.

Comment: One of the factors is decreasing, while the other is increasing (even though they're both monotonic).  It's not clear, without further computation, whether there are further critical points.

Comment: @dxiv I don't think your example works, because the minimum *is* obtained at $\pi/4$. But here is an example that proves your point: $\left(\frac{1}{\cos{x}}+\frac{1}{x^6+2\cos{x}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}}+\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^6+2\sin{x}}\right)$.

Comment: @Dan Right, thanks for the correction. My example was wrong but the point stands.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s\equiv\sin x$ and $c\equiv\cos x$ then
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=
\left(1+{1\over s^6}\right)
\left(1+{1 \over c^6}\right)
\\
&=
{s^6+1\over s^6}{c^6+1 \over c^6}
\\
&=
{(sc)^6+s^6+c^6+1\over (sc)^6}
\\
\end{align}
$$
Now $s^6+c^6=(s^2+c^2)^3-3(sc)^2(s^2+c^2)=1-3(sc)^2$
so
$$
f(x)=1+{2\over (sc)^6}-{3\over (sc)^4}\\
=1+{2\times2^6\over \sin^6 2x}
-{3\times 2^4\over\sin^42x}
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=\cos 2x\times(96/\sin^5 2x-384/\sin^72x)
$$
Since $-1\leq\sin \leq 1$ there are no solutions to $96\sin^2 2x-384=0$, the stationary point must be at $\cos 2x=0$, hence $x=\pi/4$. We can easily see it's a minimum because $f(x)$ consists of positive powers of $1/\sin 2x$,
$$
f(x)=1+{32-24\sin^2 2x\over\sin^7 2x}
$$
and
$\sin^7\leq\sin^2$, and $24\sin^2<32$, and $\sin 2x$ is a maximum at this point.

Comment: Containing reciprocal powers of sine does not imply it cannot be zero, for example $\frac{2}{\sin{x}}-\frac{1}{\sin^2{x}}$ can be zero.

Comment: How do you know the stationary point is a minimum?

Comment: @Dan - thanks for finding the flaw in my argument. In this case though there are no such solutions.

Comment: @Dan - it is positive power of $1/\sin 2x$ and $\sin 2x$ is a maximum there. Is that OK?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sin{2x}}-\left(\frac{1}{\sin{2x}}\right)^2$ consists of positive powers of $\frac{1}{\sin{2x}}$ but it has a minimum at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @Dan - you've found another flaw in my logic. Yes. OK well I'll have to change it again. Hold on a minute.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient answer than my previous approach:

Starting in the same way:
Since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos(x)$, $f(x)$ is symmetric around $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.  This implies that $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a critical point.

Writing $f(x)=(1+\sin(x)^{-6})(1+\cos(x)^{-6})$, we find that
$$
f'(x)=-6\sin(x)^{-7}\cos(x)(1+\cos(x)^{-6})+6\cos(x)^{-7}\sin(x)(1+\sin(x)^{-6}).
$$

This derivative can be factored as
$$
f'(x)=6\sin(x)^{-7}\cos(x)^{-7}(-\cos(x)^8-\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^8+\sin(x)^2).
$$

Since $\cos(x)>\sin(x)$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\cos(x)<\sin(x)$ for $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, the cosine terms dominate for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the sine terms dominate for $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore, the derivative is negative for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and positive for $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Hence, $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the global minimum.